# npm install somehow is always installing devDependendies

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm calling npm install like so:

```
NODE_ENV=production npm install --only=production --loglevel info
```

And for some reason it's installing my devDependencies as well as my normal deps? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Can you give `npm install --production` a try? Though, `--only=production` should also work.

Comment: I did try that first as the docs never mention `--only=production` :/

Comment: [They do](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install), therefore it should work: _The `--only={prod[uction]|dev[elopment]}` argument will cause either only devDependencies or only non-devDependencies to be installed regardless of the `NODE_ENV`._ Hard to say why it does not work.